# How to find the maximum sum of elements of a list with a given minimum distance between them

Tags: python, list

I have been looking for a way to find the possible combinations of a list, given a minimal distance of 3 between all the numbers.

Suppose we have

```
list = [23, 48, 10, 55, 238, 11, 12, 23, 48, 10, 55, 238, 11, 12, 23, 48, 10, 55, 238, 11]
```

The best possible combination would be 23 + 238 + 238 + 238 = 737.

I've tried parsing the list and selecting each time the max of the split list[i:i+4], like so :

23 -skip three indexes -> max of [238, 11, 12, 23] : 238 -skip three indexes -> max of [48, 10, 55, 238] : 238  skip three indexes -> max of [48, 10, 55, 238] : 238

This worked with this case, but not with other lists where I couldn't compare the skipped indexes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your stated objective ("combination") is not perfectly clear; based on your example, I imagine you mean "the maximum sum of elements of the list, given...".

Comment: Yes, sorry for the unclarity. I am indeed looking for the maximum sum of elements of the list given minimum distance between them.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify this, and add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Another thing that strikes me: the way you define "distance between elements" is unclear: the distance between the 1st 23 and the 1st 238 is 4, not 3, unless you mean the number of elements between them.

Comment: This sounds closely related to the shorted path problem: You can add an imaginary start and end node to complete the path.. Then you hop from node to node (where valid connections are those within a valid distance plus the end node).  Only now you search the longest path. Maybe this can be handled by using negative weights.

Comment: Indeed, graph theory methods would fit nicely here; I resorted to a recursive approach, but your idea is worth digging in!

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment, here is an approach using the graph algorithms in Scipy. The idea is to compute a shortest path but with the path containing negative weights corresponding to the negated list entries. This creates a longest path with the highest weights.

We start with basic definitions:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csgraph


lst = [23, 48, 10, 55, 238, 11, 12, 23, 48, 10, 55, 238, 11, 12, 23, 48,
       10, 55, 238, 11]
mindist = 4
```

List entries are nodes in a directed graph. We add an end note to that. For this graph, we create an adjacency matrix. Scipy's documentation clarifies that these are defines as such:

> If there is a connection from node i to node j, then G[i, j] = w.

For the weight w we use the negative of the list entry because algorithms are set up to find shortest routes = lowest values. Also, for the implicit connection from each node to the end of the list, we use the value -1. To make this possible, "-1" becomes our new zero and all values must be lower than that. In other words:

```py
weights = -1 - np.asarray(lst)
```

Now to the matrix:

```py
nodes = len(lst)
adjacency = np.zeros((nodes + 1, ) * 2, dtype=weights.dtype)
```

From each node, we can reach the remaining nodes. We only have to consider entries to right of the current entry.

```py
for idx in range(nodes - 1):
    remain = idx + mindist
    adjacency[idx, remain:-1] = weights[remain:]
```

At any point we can stop adding more entries to our path, read: We can directly go to the end node.

```py
adjacency[:-1, -1] = -1
```

Side note: If our input list is non-negative, adding more entries never hurts. In that case we could remove connections to the end node for inner nodes that can still reach more inner nodes. May save some time.

Now let's compute the actual shortest path from the start node index 0.

```py
dists, pred = csgraph.shortest_path(
    adjacency, return_predecessors=True, indices=0)
```

Finally, we wander the list of predecessors from end to start.

```py
cur = pred[-1]
indices = [cur]
while cur:
    cur = pred[cur]
    indices.append(cur)
indices.reverse()
```

Let's look at the results:

```py
print(indices)
print([lst[idx] for idx in indices])
```

```
[0, 4, 11, 18]
[23, 238, 238, 238]
```

Overall I'm not sure this is algorithmically superior to a simple brute-force approach. But it's certainly nice and fancy-looking ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that works, as far as I can tell.

```
list = [23, 48, 10, 55, 238, 11, 12, 23, 48, 10, 55, 238, 11, 12, 23, 48, 10, 55, 238, 11]

def max_sum(list):
    if len(list) == 0:
        return 0, ""
    elif len(list) <= 4:
        return max(list), " "+str(max(list))
    else:
        best_total = 0
        for i in range(4):
            a = max_sum(list[i+4:])
            if list[i]+a[0] > best_total:
                best_total =  list[i]+a[0]
                terms = str(list[i])+" "+a[1]
        return best_total, terms
        
def format_max_sum(list):
    a = max_sum(list)
    print("The best combination is: " + " + ".join(a[1].split())+ f" = {a[0]} ." )
    
format_max_sum(list)
# The best combination is: 23 + 238 + 238 + 238 = 737 .
```

Answer for the additional question (I only tested it on the list you provided, but it should work on any list (unless, of course, it doesn't :) ):

```
list = [23, 48, 10, 55, 238, 11, 12, 23, 48, 10, 55, 238, 11, 12, 23, 48, 10, 55, 238, 11]

def max_n_sum(list, n):
    if len(list) < 4*n-3:
        return -1, ""
    elif n == 1:
        return max(list), " "+str(max(list))
    else:
        best_total = 0
        for i in range(len(list)-4*n+4):
            a = max_n_sum(list[i+4:],n-1)
            if list[i]+a[0] > best_total:
                best_total =  list[i]+a[0]
                terms = str(list[i])+" "+a[1]
        return best_total, terms
        
def format_max_n_sum(list,n):
    a = max_n_sum(list,n)
    if a[0] == -1:
        print(f"This list is too short to support {n} values")
    else:
       b = "s" if n>1 else ""
       print(f"The best combination of {n} term" + b + " is: " + " + ".join(a[1].split())+ f" = {a[0]} ." )
    
format_max_n_sum(list, 1)
# The best combination of 1 term is: 238 = 238 .
format_max_n_sum(list, 3)
# The best combination of 3 terms is: 238 + 238 + 238 = 714 .
format_max_n_sum(list, 6)
# This list is too short to support 6 values
```

Explanation of the calculus:

- To support n values, the list must have at least this size:(o = valid values, xxx = 3 values skipped): o xxx o xxx o xxx o ... xxx o , so 4n - 3 values for n "o"s.
- If the list is long enough, it is shaped like this:
  OOOOOO xxx o xxx o xxx o ... xxx o , OOOOOO being the valid candidates for the first of the n values; and their number is len(list) - (4n - 4) .

Comment: Legendary code, how about getting only n number of numbers? For example, if I wanted to get the best sum of two numbers that have a minimum distance of 4 between them, would I use a recursive approach?

Comment: For only 2 numbers, I'd probably do the brute force approach. But I'll have to think about a general approach for n numbers.

Comment: After thinking about it more, I believe (but didn't test) that you could adapt the recursive approach for finding the best sum of n numbers, by adding a counter to the function; furthermore, you'd have to adapt the length check (if you want to find 3 numbers for example, you must leave at least 1 + 3 + 1 numbers for the 2nd iteration).

Comment: Do you have a code representation of the idea? I tried implementing the counter, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I had some ideas when I wrote my comment, but it was House of the Dragon time... I'll work on the code now!

Comment: Here you are, enjoy :)